# FACETS : Add "Apply" button that will apply all filters in one query

Tags: 8, search

Is it possible in D8 to add an "Apply" button that will apply all facet filters in one query and not having an ajax reload on each option changed ?

i find this for D7 :

https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_facets/issues/2700063

i am not quite sure  what's been the issue of that issue.

Comment: Isn't this counter point to what facets are?

Comment: Not sure i get your point and i quite like the ajax behaviour of the facets but when using more than one facet ,our UX designer consider that selecting all filters before applying is better, particularely when a selection of one make the others disappearing

Comment: why exposed filters have an apply button by default and facets have an option on change behaviour by default?

Answer (score 1):

i have created an issue on the facet module and the situation is :

Not soon in the drupal 8 version. This would be a big refactor of the way queries are built right now.

https://www.drupal.org/project/facets/issues/3013702